# How can I remove 3-way switch to leave single pole switch on the lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, multiway-switch

I would like to install a Leviton Decora Smart DW6HD in a 3-way scenario. One switch is a simple on/off while the switch being replaced is a dimming switch but do not think that matters. I tried installing the new switch but after much frustration read that the DW6HD does not support standard 3-way switch and must be used with a DD00R-L. I do not care to purchase a second smart-switch for the same room. I would like to eliminate the second switch so the 6W6HD may be wired as a single pole. I have found a number of articles explaining how to do this but my scenario seems to be a little different. At each box there are two white wires capped together, two black and a red wire connected to each switch. Thoughts on how to handle this?

Switch A to be replaced:

- Two White capped together
- Ground
- Red to Red
- Red/White to Black
- Black to Black

[image: Switch A]

Switch B to be removed:

- Two White capped together
- Ground
- Red
- Black
- Black

[image: Switch B]

New switch to replace Switch A

[image: Replacement switch]

Comment: if you look in the back of the box you will see the wires are grouped into cables or sometimes conduit pipes.  How they are grouped is absolutely essential to describing the circuit.

Comment: Correct, they are grouped so I was able to determine the set containing the red wire wire leading to the second switch.

Comment: If you want us to help, you may want to describe to us how they are grouped.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out per the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following changes:

For the switch being replaced, connected the black wire to BK, the other black wire to RD, and the two white wires that were capped together are now connected to WH on the new switch.

For the switch being removed, left two white wires capped together and capped two black wires together.

The red wire is no longer used on either end (switch) and is now capped.